# X_VERIFY_CREDENTIALS_AUTHORIZATION - where can i get those values?

Tags: twitter, oauth, echo, token

A curl HEADER should contain the following:

```
oauth_consumer_key="YOUR KEY HERE",     
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
oauth_token="YOUR TOKEN HERE",         
oauth_timestamp="TIMESTAMP", 
oauth_nonce="OAUTH NONCE", 
oauth_version="1.0", 
oauth_signature="SIGNATURE"
```

where can i get the consumer_key, a valid oauth_token, timestamp, nonce, signature??

vic,
thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specification to generate a proper OAuth request is here: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849

It is pretty complicated so I would recommend using an open source library to do the heavy lifting. You can find one here: http://oauth.net/code/

Where you get your consumer key depends on what API you are using. Twitter for example is http://dev.twitter.com/apps, and FourSquare is http://foursquare.com/oauth/.

Comment: thanx, i used a library (jaisenmathai-php)and get the right values, but twitter always say "could not authenticate you.." ;-)